# Nginx cannot access a Docker volume mount

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-volume

I have a Docker Compose setup to run a Nginx serving pictures (`jpg` files). The port, protocol, etc. is not relevant. My Nginx works correctly and serve those files:

```
 web:
  image: myweb
  restart: always
  volumes:
 - ./logs/nginx:/var/log/nginx
  ports:
 ...
```

The image `myweb` inherits from `nginx` and add all the configuration needed by this server, basically, the web root is:

```
  index index.html index.php;
  root /var/www/myweb/public;
```

I'm also using `php:7.0-fpm` and `fastcgi` locations but it is not the issue here.

What I would want is to **mount a host volume with the pictures** (instead of copying them into the *docker image*) in order to have the possibility of update it externally (Dropbox sync or whatever).

```
 web:
  image: myweb
  restart: always
  volumes:
 - ./webcode:/var/www
 - ./logs/nginx:/var/log/nginx
 - ./images-data/catalog-images:/var/www/myweb/public/catalog/images
  ports:
 ...
```

The host path `webcode` (relative to *docker-compose.yml* location) is the static web, also mounted on `/var/www`.
The host path `images-data/catalog-images` (relative to *docker-compose.yml* location) is the pictures directory, mounted on `/var/www/myweb/public/catalog/images`.

I'm not sure it this is a good practice (mount a host directory on the same path where other host directory was already mounted). Anyway, I also tried keeping `webcode` as part of the `myweb` image having only one mounted volume (the pictures one).

Mounting `webcode` and including pictures on it, works. And without any volume mount, just including all the stuff (website and pictures), also works. But I would need to have an isolated volume for the pictures.
I also tried symlinking within the container `/var/www/myweb/public/catalog/images` towards the pictures volume. But Nginx does not render it, perhaps because it it a different volume than `/var/www`.

Should it belong to the `root` of `nginx` server configuration ?

The thing is that, those images are not loaded in the browser. Going into the container, I confirm that the ownership for the volume is correct (`www-data:www-data`).

From the point of view of the container, ownership and content is the same if I mount the volume or if I copy in the container filesystem. But Nginx only can see the files within the Docker container file system.

Is this the normal behaviour ? Am I missing any Nginx configuration to work normally with host volumes inside the container ?

Answer (score 0):

I think I finally solved.
When I said

> I'm also using php:7.0-fpm and fastcgi locations **but it is not the
>   issue here**.

I was totally wrong: it was the key: the `php` execution. The problem was that the pictures was loaded by an `index.php`. Then it was sent to the `fpm` service where the pictures were not available !!.
This is my `docker-compose.yml` definition for the `php` service:

```
 fpm:
  image: php7fpm:latest
  restart: always
  volumes:
  - ./webcode:/var/www
```

The thing is that the pictures volume was not visible there. I just added such volume to `fpm` volume list, and problem is solved:

```
 fpm:
  image: php7fpm:latest
  restart: always
  volumes:
  - ./webcode:/var/www
  - ./images-data/catalog-images:/var/www/myweb/public/catalog/images
```

Sorry for the inconvenience.